# Polyfill for Internet Explorer ECMAScript Set constructor to allow iterable argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wrote some code using the constructor described in the [MDN docs for the Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Unfortunately Internet Explorer 11 ignores any iterable argument in the constructor. I had a quick attempt at trying to override the constructor (code below) but with no luck (Set.prototype.size returns - 'this' is not a set object).

```
var testSet = new Set([0]);
if (testSet.size === 0) {
    //constructor doesnt take an iterable as an argument - thanks IE
    var oldProto = Set.prototype
    Set = function (iterable) {
        if (iterable) {
            iterable.forEach(this.add.bind(this));
        }
    };
    Set.prototype = oldProto;
}
```

Is there a way to allow the Set constructor to have an iterable argument passed and still work in I.E. ? I guess next best option will be to create some kind of factory method (Set.create) which returns a new Set instance.

Comment: Have you explored using existing polyfills like `core-js`? This isn'y really something I'd recommend implementing yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were not creating a new `Set` instance in that code. If you wanted to overwrite the constructor, you should do

```
if (new Set([0]).size === 0) {
    //constructor doesnt take an iterable as an argument - thanks IE
    const BuiltinSet = Set;
    Set = function Set(iterable) {
        const set = new BuiltinSet();
        if (iterable) {
            iterable.forEach(set.add, set);
        }
        return set;
    };
    Set.prototype = BuiltinSet.prototype;
    Set.prototype.constructor = Set;
}
```

Comment: Stealing (with credit and link to here) - Thanks Bergi! (funny, I also often include a comment like _"Thanks IE!"_ or _"Thanks Microsoft!"_)